# Call Procedure Unexpected error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, package

I'm coding a DML package, and I would like create a simple procedure within package to updated commission_pct value. I don't receive any syntax error when I execute the package body but when I call the procedure I receive a unexpected error. Thanks.

```
PROCEDURE update_commission_pct(
    p_empid     employees.employee_id%TYPE,
    p_new_comm  employees.commission_pct%TYPE
    )
  IS
    rec_confirm   employees%ROWTYPE;
    v_valid_empid BOOLEAN;
  BEGIN
    -- Simple boolean function to check employee existence
    v_valid_empid := dml_employees_pkg.check_employee_id(p_empid);

     IF
      v_valid_empid = TRUE 
      AND LENGTH(p_new_comm) <=5 THEN
        UPDATE    employees
        SET       commission_pct = p_new_comm
        WHERE     employee_id = p_empid
        RETURNING employee_id, commission_pct
        INTO      rec_confirm.employee_id, rec_confirm.commission_pct;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Comission updated successfully.');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee ID number ' ||
                             rec_confirm.employee_id || ' new comm is' ||
                             rec_confirm.commission_pct);
    ELSE
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20042, 'Employee ID ' || 
                                p_empid || ' Employee doesn't exist.');
    END IF;
  END update_commission_pct;
```

Call procedure in a simple PL/SQL block:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
  dml_employees_pkg.update_commission_pct(550, 10);
END;
```

Oracle ERROR:

```
Informe de error -
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
ORA-06512: at "HR.DML_EMPLOYEES_PKG", line 118
ORA-06512: at line 2
01438. 00000 -  "value larger than specified precision allowed for this column"
*Cause:    When inserting or updating records, a numeric value was entered
           that exceeded the precision defined for the column.
*Action:   Enter a value that complies with the numeric column's precision,
           or use the MODIFY option with the ALTER TABLE command to expand
           the precision.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `commission_pct` column in the `employees` table ([in the default HR schema](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10831/scripts.htm#CHDFBADB)) is defined as `number(2, 2)`.

The meaning of the precision and scale [is explained inthe documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020), but essentially here it means the column can only accept values from 0.00 to 0.99. You're trying to insert 10, which - as the error says - exceeds the allowed precision.

If you want to store 10% you can either pass 0.1 as the second argument in your procedure call; or stick with passing 10 but then divide by 100 as part of the update statement:

```
SET       commission_pct = p_new_comm/100
```

You may want to validate the passed value in some way other than checking its length. And at the moment if the `LENGTH(p_new_comm) <=5` check fails, the raised exception doesn't make that clear - it only refers to the employee ID which may actually be valid. The length check doesn't really sense anyway though.

Comment: I understand. I check commission_pct column and I think about 99.99 was the max value for this column. Thanks sir for your help. I vote your answer.